# output not reflecting in cronjob

Tags: shell, cron

I have a script which send the output of a command. The command takes few seconds to execute. But when I put the command in the cron, the output is not reflected in the mail received nor in the file from where the script fetches the output.

```
echo "$(date)" > /home/checks.txt  
status=`sysstatus`
echo "$(sysstatus)">> /home/checks.txt

for MAIL in abc@xyz.com def@xyz.com
do
mailx -s "$Date Daily check on system" "$MAIL" < /home/checks.txt
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to show your attempts. Also, use the tools there to format the question properly.

Comment: the command sysstatus take sfew seconds to execute so the cron doesnt provides the correct output as desired.

Comment: cron runs in its own environment, it may not have `systatus` in `$PATH`. Try using the full location of `systatus` - eg `/usr/bin/sysstatus` or wherever.

Comment: still it does not showing the result in the email triggered. when i run the script manually it gives the output in  the mail triggered, but not in the cron.

Comment: The script is running fine when run manually. The output received via email is same as that of the file. When cron executes it, the command status doesnt execute or its output is not redirected in the file and so is in the email triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving full path to the command status in the script solved the issue.